# Reading existing entities with multiple conditions

Tags: magento2, model

I can get data from database by calling model factory in controller.

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

protected $_entityFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \My\Module\Model\EntityFactory $entityFactory
){
    $this->_entityFactory = $entityFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){
    $entity = $this->_entityFactory->create();

    // get data where entity_id = 1
    $entity->load(1);

    // get data where entity_name = Rizki
    $entity->load('Rizki', 'entity_name');
}
```

Now, i want get data with multiple condition. I have tried

`$entity->load(['Rizki', 'entity_name'], ['Bandung' => 'address'])`

But it gives me error **Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`:

```
/**
 * Load object data
 *
 * @param integer $modelId
 * @param null|string $field
 * @return $this
 * @deprecated
 */
public function load($modelId, $field = null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($modelId, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $modelId, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    $this->updateStoredData();
    return $this;
}
```

There is no such `load` method for AbstractModel instance with array parameters. Therefore, to load model using multiple conditions, my favorite method is like this:

```
$model = $modelFactory
    ->create()
    ->getResource()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('[field_name_1]', '[value_1]')
    ->addFieldToFilter('[field_name_2]', '[value_2]')
    ->getFirstItem()
;
```